Maintaining Context Between Model-Driven App and Custom Copilot Chat Interface
I'm developing a model-driven app using Microsoft Power Apps and have extended the side pane to include a custom Copilot chat interface. The chat works as intended, but I'm facing challenges with maintaining context based on user interactions in the left-side form.
Problem Description:
In my app, the left pane displays a hierarchical structure of folders along with a list of files contained within each folder. When a user selects a file from this list, I want to enable them to ask questions related to that specific file in the custom chat interface on the right side.
Goals:
Context Awareness: When a file is selected, the chat interface should recognize this selection and maintain context, allowing the user to inquire about details specific to that file.
Dynamic Interaction: The chat should dynamically adjust to the context of the selected file so that relevant questions and answers can be facilitated seamlessly.
Questions:

How can I programmatically pass the context of the selected file from
the left pane to the Copilot chat interface? What are best practices
for maintaining state or context in a model-driven app, especially
when integrating with a custom chat interface?

Any advice, code snippets, or resources that can help me solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/guidance/pass-context-variables-from-webpage-to-copilot
Was able to achieve the requirement using this doc
